# (Visual Basic Console Mode) Check numbers from 1 to 7 and print certain output?

Tags: vb.net

Question : **Request a user to input a number from 1 to 7. If the number is 1 to 5. Output "Weekday" if 6 or 7 then "Weekend". Else show an error.**

This is what I tried to do.

```
Imports System

Module Program
  Dim num1 As Integer

  Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number from 1 to 7")
    num1 = Console.ReadLine
    If num1 = 1 Or 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5 Then
        Console.Write("It is a school day")
    ElseIf num1 = 6 Or 7 Then
        Console.WriteLine("It is the weekend")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Beep! error, enter number from 1 to 7")

    End If
    Console.ReadKey()

  End Sub
End Module
```

I think the error is in *If num1 = 1 or 2 or 3...*
What is the correct way to phrase that statement?
Thanks

Comment: `1 Or 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5` = 7, `Console.ReadLine()` returns a string. Set `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit On`

Comment: As mentioned `Console.ReadLine` will return a string, so you need to convert the input into a number first. At the moment, it's probably doing an implicit conversion, but what if the user types in 'c' or 'A'? Also, the If statement doesn't do what you think it does. It needs to be broken out. `If num1 = 1 or num1 = 2 or num1 = 3...` and so on.... as it is, it's doing a logical or rather than a comparison or on the numbers, which isn't what you want.  I'd also probably go with an OrElse rather than a plain Or so that as soon as it finds a match, it'll stop and drop into the if case.

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicions are correct.  The problem is with your `or` syntax.  The correct syntax would be

```
If num1 = 1 Or num1 = 2 Or num1 = 3 Or num1 = 4 Or num1 = 5 Then
    Console.Write("It is a school day")
ElseIf num1 = 6 Or num1 = 7 Then
    Console.WriteLine("It is the weekend")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Beep! error, enter number from 1 to 7")
End If
```

Of course it would be simpler if you used a `Select Case` statement.

```
Select Case num1 
   Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5:
      Console.Write("It is a school day")
   Case 6, 7:
      Console.WriteLine("It is the weekend")
   Case Else
      Console.WriteLine("Beep! error, enter number from 1 to 7")
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Console.ReadLine returns a String. So, it cannot be directly assigned to an Integer. First, we check if a number was entered. If it isn't a number we can't compare it to other numbers. Integer.TryParse returns True if the input is a number and fills in the second parameter with the number.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim input As String
    Dim num1 As Integer
    Do
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number from 1 to 7")
        input = Console.ReadLine
    Loop Until Integer.TryParse(input, num1)

    Select Case num1
        Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
            Console.WriteLine("It is a school day")
        Case 6, 7
            Console.WriteLine("It is the weekend")
        Case Else
            Beep()
            Console.WriteLine("Error, you didn't enter a number from 1 to 7")
    End Select

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```